# connection closed by remote host when trying to remote ssh to ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I installed ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS and it is up and running. I also installed openssh-server to my Linux distro and ssh is also up and running. Now when I ssh into my linux server from a different PC on the same LAN I can successfully login and access my server. What I was trying to do is access my server remotely through the internet so I used the same method as I used for LAN ssh connection but with my public IP `ssh username@myPublicIp` but when I do this I get error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host Connection closed by myPublicIp port 22`. Why is this happening and what is the right way to ssh remotely through the internet to my Linux server? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I added a port forwarding rule on my router. Port forward configuration screen shot attached below.

**NOTE:** I also tried setting up DMZ on my router but that didn't help either.
[image]

Comment: Check the syslogs on the ssh server host for any log entries related to your ssh connection attempts. You want to see if the sshd process is logging anything about receiving these connection attempts and if it is, why it's closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that your requests are being blocked by your router. By default a home router will block incoming packets from outside the local network unless the connection was initiated by a device in said network (i.e. a web server sending a web page in response to your device sending an HTTP request would be allowed through). If you're accessing the server remotely, then you need to setup port forwarding on your router. Your router manufacturer should have a guide on how to do that if you don't know already or you can look it up online. However, you should be careful when opening ports, as when you do it can be accessed by anyone, including attackers trying to gain access to your network for malicious purposes. Since it is just ssh, make sure you use a secure password for ssh or use RSA keys. Another tool you may want to look into would be [fail2ban](https://www.howtogeek.com/675010/how-to-secure-your-linux-computer-with-fail2ban/). This will block IP addresses trying to connect after a set number of failed attempts.

Comment: take a look at my edit above I tried it with port forwarding but I still get the same error.